# What was the earlier expose of racism that Twain wrote that was censored?

Tags: mark-twain, censorship

[This article](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/789/adventures-of-huckleberry-finn) claims

> Ironically, Huck Finn was conceived only after an earlier explicit
> exposé by Twain of slavery was censored.

Does anyone have more information about this earlier expose? The name, the actual contents  would be nice, why it was censored.

Answer (score 16):

I think that this references the same incident described by [Shelley Fisher Fishkin](https://profiles.stanford.edu/shelley-fishkin?releaseVersion=10.5.2) in her essay *[Mark Twain, Race, and Huckleberry Finn](https://nanopdf.com/download/mark-twain-race-and-huckleberry-finn_pdf)*. Fishkin notes that in *Huckleberry Finn*, Twain "explored  the  subject  of  racism through satire and irony" a strategy he developed "when a direct expose of racism that he wrote was censored" - very similar to the wording of the article cited in the question. Fishkin describes the events as follows.

> As  a  young  reporter  in  San  Francisco  in  the  mid-1860s,  Twain
> witnessed  an  incident  he  considered  outrageous:  several
> policemen stood idly by, apparently amused, as young white hooligans
> attacked a Chinese man who was going about his business. Twain’s
> publishers refused to run the account he wrote of the incident, caring
> more about not  offending  the  paper’s  subscribers  (who  shared
> the  police’s prejudices) than about the truth. **Twain quickly
> learned that exposés of racism in San Francisco would not be printed
> in newspapers there**.

The incident concerns racism rather than slavery, but it seems to be relevant to the ironic form that *Finn* took, and definitely involves censorship.

In *The Autobiography of Mark Twain*, the text is quoted as:

> One Sunday afternoon I saw some hoodlums chasing and stoning a
> Chinaman who was heavily laden with the weekly wash of his Christian
> customers, and I noticed that a policeman was observing this
> performance with an amused interest—nothing more.

According to *[Mark Twain’s Racial Ideologies and His Portrayal of the Chinese](http://www.concentric-literature.url.tw/issues/M/3.pdf)*, an article published by Hsin-yun Ou (Concentric: Literary and Cultural Studies 36.2Sept. 2010: 33-59)

> Twain rewrote the story with a satirical strategy of irony, and
> published it in a paper in  the  next  state  and  in  a  national
> magazine. In  “What  Have  the  Police Been Doing?”  (Territorial
> Enterprise [Virginia  City],  Jan.  16-18,  1866),  the  narrator,
> posing  as  the  policemen’s  loyal  friend,  satirizes  corrupt
> police  officers  who constantly victimized the local Chinese
> population.

Comment: The most famous piece Twain [did get published about attacks on Chinese-Americans in San Francisco](https://americanliterature.com/author/mark-twain/short-story/disgraceful-persecution-of-a-boy) was biting satire.

Comment: Twain who pitied Chinese-Americans was an Indian (Native American) hater himself.